# Quarkus framework was created from the core of the Spring framework?

Tags: spring, quarkus

I would like to know if the **Quarkus framework** was created from the *core* of the **Spring framework** ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It was not. Out of curiosity, what gave you the impression that something like that might be the case?

Comment: Quarkus code has nothing to do with Spring code.